# Configure UrlReplacer to only work for specific IP addresses

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing, friendly-url, immediacy

I'm using a utility called [UrlReplacer](http://www.motobit.com/help/url-replacer-rewriter/iis-mod-rewrite.asp) to enable the configuration of friendly Urls for a website I'm working on.  The website is developed in Asp.Net 3.5 and uses [Immediacy CMS](http://www.immediacy.net/).

We need to allow the client to manage their own friendly URLs. Is there any way that UrlReplacer can be set up so that the configuration page is only visible to certain IP addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting the author of the software it seems that this is not possible.